# VSCode: How to Step Over

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I have VSCode Windows and Microsoft Python extension installed.

By pressing F5, the IDE just executes my code immediately. I don't get the chance to choose if I want to run the code or to use debugging features like step-over or step-into. The debugging menu bar appears on top and disappears very quickly.

In some tutorial videos I see that pressing F5 actually brings up that menu bar. Then the developer has to choose to run the program or step it. I want the same thing.

Please assist.

Comment: add a breakpoint somewhere in your code, start of main

Answer (score 2):

so first you have to add a breakpoint in which the debugger will pause at the line of code. You can add the breakpoint by pressing f9 in the same line of the code. After that, you can press f5 to debug the code and later on press f10 to step over!